# Pandas: Unjoin a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a large table of data in pandas that could possibly be better represented as multiple relational tables. Is there a way to pick the columns to use in a new dataframe and to index the leftover columns to allow a join to recreate the original table?

For example, lets say we have a dataset where some columns get repeated multiple times over several rows:

```
data = {
        '1': ['A', 'Abe', 'Bucket', '2022-01-01', 1,0], 
        '2': ['A', 'Abe', 'Bucket', '2022-01-02', 0,1], 
        '3': ['A', 'Abe', 'Bucket', '2022-01-03', 3,3], 
        '4': ['A', 'Abe', 'Bucket with Hole', '2022-01-04', 3,1], 
        '5': ['B', 'Ben', 'Jug', '2022-01-01', 2,1], 
        '6': ['C', 'Cat', 'Jug', '2022-01-01', 1,2]}

joined_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, 
                   orient='index',
                       columns=['Sample', 'Author','Instrument', 'Date', 'Data1','Data2'])
joined_df
```

returns

```
Sample  Author  Instrument  Date    Data1   Data2
1   A   Abe Bucket  2022-01-01  1   0
2   A   Abe Bucket  2022-01-02  0   1
3   A   Abe Bucket  2022-01-03  3   3
4   A   Abe Bucket with Hole    2022-01-04  3   1
5   B   Ben Jug 2022-01-01  2   1
6   C   Cat Jug 2022-01-01  1   2
```

how can I go about splitting the data so that I have an "Sample" dataframe, "Time" dataframe, and "Data" dataframe:

```
Data:
Sample_ID   Instrument_ID   Date    Data1   Data2
d1  s1  i1  2022-01-01  1   0
d2  s1  i1  2022-01-02  0   1
d3  s1  i1  2022-01-03  3   3
d4  s1  i2  2022-01-04  3   1
d5  s2  i3  2022-01-01  2   1
d6  s3  i3  2022-01-01  1   2
```

and

```
Samples:
Sample  Name
s1  A   Abe
s2  B   Ben
s3  C   Cat

Instument
i1  bucket
i2  Bucket with Hole
i3  Jug
```

Joining the sample and data dataframes on the SampleID should return the original table

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this to 3x relational tables? One containing info on the sample (date, location etc), one on the sampler (name, institute, email) and the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the dummy dataset but I'm not sure about the performance on a large dataset. Might need to test with Parquet and a "real" dataset. The steps are first to create each relational table, drop duplicates, and then remerge to the original dataset to match indexes:

```
sample_df = joined_df[['Sample','Author']].drop_duplicates().rename_axis('SampleID').reset_index()
instrument_df = joined_df[['Instrument']].drop_duplicates().rename_axis('InstrumentID').reset_index()

    SampleID    Sample  Author
0   1   A   Abe
1   5   B   Ben
2   6   C   Cat

    InstrumentID    Instrument
0   1   Bucket
1   4   Bucket with Hole
2   5   Jug 

df3 = joined_df.merge(instrument_df, on=["Instrument"])
df3 = df3.merge(sample_df, on=["Sample","Author"])
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['Sample','Author','Instrument'])
df3

    Date    Data1   Data2   InstrumentID    SampleID
0   2022-01-01  1   0   1   1
1   2022-01-02  0   1   1   1
2   2022-01-03  3   3   1   1
3   2022-01-04  3   1   4   1
4   2022-01-01  2   1   5   5
5   2022-01-01  1   2   5   6
```